# How to assign more than one attribute to the html element with thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a select box on my thymelaf page. I already have defined one attribute for it like:

```
th:attr="labelId='associateTSF' + ${mViewStat.index}"
```

Is there a way to set more than one? something like:

```
th:attr="labelId='associateTSF' + ${mViewStat.index}; missionGroup=${mView.missionGroup}"
```

I have already tried this with ; and with blank space, no success. All examples I have found are with single value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Found it! And it works. It should be separated by comma.

> HTML forbids repeated attributes, so that code is not correct.
>   However, th:attr and data-th-attr allow you to specify several
>   attributes separated by commas, like:

```
 <a href="#"     data-th-attr="data-groupid=${somevalue},
                  data-groupname=${someothervalue}">...</a>
```

found it on this discussion:
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/93

Comment: Sweet as, swaz - much appreciated

Answer (score 23):

This worked for me

```
th:attr="attrParam1=${attrVal1}, 
         width=${width != null ? width : null}, 
         height=${height != null ? height : null}"
```